# Ag grid sizeColumnsToFit only when there is space available in the total grid width

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

Is there some function available to adjust the column width to fit the entire grid (basically call the following

> api.sizeColumnsToFit()

only when there are not enough headers to fill in the empty space available in the total width.[image]

Answer (score 4):

i know its a bit late, but you know... better too late than never ;-)

```
  /**
   * resizes the columns to fit the width of the grid
   * @param allowShrink if false, columns will NOT be resized when there is no "empty" horizontal space
   */
  public resizeColumnsToFit(allowShrink = true) {
    if (this.gridApi) {
      if (allowShrink) {
        this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
      } else {
        /**
         * this is a "hacK" - there is no way to check if there is "empty" space in the grid using the
         * public grid api - we have to use the internal tools here.
         * it could be that some of this apis will change in future releases
         */
        const panel = this.gridApi["gridPanel"];
        const availableWidth = this.gridApi["gridPanel"].eBodyViewport.clientWidth;
        const columns = this.gridApi["gridPanel"]["columnController"].getAllDisplayedColumns();
        const usedWidth = this.gridApi["gridPanel"]["columnController"].getWidthOfColsInList(columns);

        if (usedWidth < availableWidth) {
          this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can use this method to conditionally resize the columns of the grid. Use `resizeColumnsToFit(false)` if you don't want to resize the columns when there is a horizontal scroll bar.

Credit: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1772